# Is System.Security.Cryptography using SIMD optimisation?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, simd, sha256

I tried to look into SHA-256 calculations with reflector. But it goes somewhere into *unmanaged code*.

What I am trying to find is if the .NET System.Security.Cryptography implementation can be optimized. With use of SIMD for example.

So the question is - will .NET 4.6+ SHA-256 use SIMD or not. And if not - can performance be improved by using SIMD or the current implementation is the pretty much the best there is?

EDIT: the dll I use currently is using CAPI native code inside Microsoft System.Security.Cryptography and the code it calls is **unmanaged** and I cannot find source for it atm..

The managed implementation https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha256managed.cs seems not to be using SIMD.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha256managed.cs

Comment: No.  It is already optimized if you are using Net 4.6+   See https://instil.co/2016/03/21/parallelism-on-a-single-core-simd-with-c/

Comment: @pteberf - thank you. I couldn't find that one..

Comment: @jdweng SIMD in .NET can only be used if you use System.Numerics. so the "No" in your comment - what does it mean? No - I cannot improve speed of hashing? But *it seems* .NET SHA256 doesn't use Numerics (according to the link by @pteberf)..

Comment: What I meant by no is the Net 4.6+ already takes advantage of SMID according to the article.   See follow on article : https://instil.co/2016/04/07/simd-performance-and-cost-with-csharp-and-cpp/

Comment: I am sorry but you misunderstood my question and the comments.

Comment: The implementation inside CAPI or CNG is undoubtedly using optimized instruction flows. The *Managed types don’t, but they were just a bridge for letting Win9x use the algorithms because the OS didn’t support them, and you should not use them directly (just trust (e.g.) `SHA256.Create()`)

Comment: yes optimized. but to what degree? does it use avx2? avx512? and how can I manage that? for example I have Amazon.Glacier dll which uses sha256 managed instead of Cng.. I want to make it use what I need not what it set to use by default..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to look into SHA-256 calculations with reflector. But it goes somewhere into unmanaged code.

Most of the cryptography in .NET is just a wrapper over the functionality provided by system libraries.  There are a few historical exceptions in .NET Framework (e.g. SHA256Managed), but those are no longer present in .NET Core (e.g. [SHA256Managed is no longer managed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/331563bbe49eed6c029ffcaad4ba43f36bc7b07b/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA256Managed.cs), the type name simply exists for compatibility).

> What I am trying to find is if the .NET System.Security.Cryptography implementation can be optimized. With use of SIMD for example.

System.Security.Cryptography is a large namespace, with lots of different things in it. Since you mention SHA-2-256 specifically, we can break it down a bit.

- SHA256CryptoServiceProvider

  - This uses the SHA-2-256 implementation from CAPI (crypt32.dll/advapi32.dll/etc).
  - On Windows 10 (and possibly some older Windows versions) the implementation in crypt32/etc just forwards to the CNG implementation.
- SHA256Cng

  - This uses the SHA-2-256 implementation from CNG (bcrypt.dll).
  - Windows 8 had a minimum CPU requirement of the SSE2 instruction set, so at minimum it likely uses an SSE2 speedup.
  - The AES implementation uses AES-NI when available, so the library already has patterns of probing for new instruction sets and having fallback implementations.
  - The most reasonable expectation is that if there's a speed improvement that could be made with an instruction set that had an in-market CPU one year before the release of the version of Windows (or the 6-month update for Windows 10) then the CNG team probably has made an optimized version using that instruction.
- SHA256Managed

  - In .NET Core this is just a wrapper over another implementation.
  - In .NET Framework what you see on referencesource is what you get.
  - Could it be sped up? Probably.
  - Will it? Seems rather unlikely; the use of the type is discouraged.

> (from comments: does it use avx2? avx512?)

Dunno. Theoretically you could step into / disassemble the native implementation and find out. The oldest processor I can find with AVX-512 is 
[Intel Core i7-7800X](https://ark.intel.com/products/123589/), from Q2 2017.  The most recent FIPS CAVP certificate for Windows I can find right now is SHS#4253 (3/9/2018), so there's a chance that AVX-512 is in use on the newest releases of Windows 10.

> (re: avx2/avx512 for sha256) and how can I manage that?

AFAIK, you can't; aside from joining that team (https://careers.microsoft.com).

> for example I have Amazon.Glacier dll which uses sha256 managed instead of Cng.. I want to make it use what I need not what it set to use by default.

You'd need to get Amazon to change to using `SHA256.Create()`.  There's not really a practical way of changing someone else's code (unless it's open-source that accepts contributions... in which case, you can try changing it directly).

Comment: yes thank you.. by far best info.. Re: Glacier - I have recreated today whatever they use in my own code and supply my own hashes using Cng. 48% speed boost.

Comment: P.S. Xeons from Aug 2015 should have AVX512 too, so its not too exotic